# timeago Jquery Plugin Date Format Problem

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, timeago

Here we go:  I"m trying to implement the timeago jquery plugin (http://timeago.yarp.com/) on my project to show relative time (.i.e "2mins ago" instead of "1.10pm").  I have a field in my MySQL database which stores the timestamp of the current entry.

However, the timeago jquery plugin only works when the time is in UTC format "2008-07-17T09:24:17Z"

My first problem is:  How to convert mysql timestamp to the above required format.
My second problem:  Even when I hardcode the required format in my code, the plugin does not work.  Why?

My hardcode:
In php file 1:

```
echo '<abbr class="timestamp" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>';
```

In index.php file 2

```
$("abbr.timestamp").timeago();
```

Of course, I've included the script tag properly.  I can't figure out why it's not working.  Note:  I'm working on XAMPP, on my own computer (local).

Comment: You seem to be asking the same question over and over. Maybe you should upload a non-working complete example at http://jsfiddle.net, so we can have a look.

Comment: yeah, I felt that I didn't make myself completely clear the last time.  So here I'm clarifying things... :)

Comment: [I'm using timeago myself](https://github.com/deceze/jquery-timeago) without any problems. I think we can't offer any more help without seeing a complete example.

Comment: ok, going to give you the whole thing.

Comment: here you go - given you the whole code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `echo date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime('2011-02-16 12:26:00'));`
2. Are you executing `timeago` when the DOM has finished loading? I.e.:

   ```
   jQuery(function ($) {
       $("abbr.timestamp").timeago();
   }
   ```

Comment: yes, I'm executing the timeago function when DOM is ready.  Still not working.  I'm frustrated.

Comment: I've downloaded your own timeago package from github...and it works ok.

Comment: @the Then your copy was "bad"? My fork has only minimal changes from the latest original...

Comment: nope, I've stripped down your copy to only the paragraph of 'Ryan was born..' put it on a web server, and it works.  I transfer the same code to my php files, it doesn't work.

Comment: you think another plugin might be causing conflict?  Firebug reports nothing though.

Comment: @the *shrug* :) Strip your own example down as much as possible as well, to bare HTML. Then build back up again from there...

Comment: hey, thanks for all your help - I've solved the problem.  Indeed, when I stripped down all the code, they was a bug on the line before the timeago function was called, hence preventing it from executing.  Problem solved.

Comment: Now gonna check the time conversion problem.

Comment: lol, hope I'm not bothering you with all my noob questions.  But here we go again...does the abbr tag content has to be in a specified format? <abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>  Does it have to be "July 17, 2008" because when I change it to some random text, it doesn't work.

Comment: @the No, neither the HTML standard nor timeago care about what's in there. I'd guess you're breaking the syntax again?

Comment: If I replace the "July 17, 2008" with the word "time"  it stops working :O  Doesn't work even in your files.

Comment: @the Sorry to disappoint, but it works fine whatever you put there. Just tested it.

Comment: you should really kick me.  My mistake sorry.  Thanks for all your help.  You're by far the most patient person I've met here. :)

Comment: All woking fine.  Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$time=time(); // Current timestamp eg: 1371612613
$formatted_time=date("c", $time); // Converts to date format 2014-09-12T02:30:13+00:00
```

js code

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("abbr.timestamp").timeago();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This plugin worked with mysql default timestamp in case of mine. put your timestamp in the title.Try this once:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      jQuery("div.myRelativeTimestamp").timeago();
})
</script>
<div class="myRelativeTimestamp" title="<?php echo $row->time; ?>"></div>
```